# Jade render's my html twice

Tags: express, pug

Maybe I'm asking my question wrong since it seems like the answer should be relatively easy to search for. I am parsing some .md files in express and returning the response to a jade template.

`= body` returns `<h1>my content</h1>` as a string.
`#{body}` returns `&lt;<h1>my content</h1>&gt;<!--<h1-->my content&gt;` or effectively:

```
<
my content #as a styled h1

>my content>
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE FOR CLARITY:
My question is - why is the content returning twice.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Added an update - basically, why is it returning the comment twice, once in a botched comment and once as rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the content returning twice.

Because with the syntax of `#{VARIABLE}` Jade replace the variable with the value and interpret it as a HTML tag. For example:

passing a local variable `{foo: 'bar'}` and this template

```
#{foo}
```

generat this HTML

```
<bar></bar>
```

So you should pass the content and don't let interpret it by jade using `=` or `!=` for unbuffered code:

```
!=body
```

btw: a whitespace is forbidden between `=` and the variable!